# Is is possible two tablets of the same model has different functionalities?

Tags: tablet, hardware

I've bought a [Huawei IDEOS S7](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ideos_s7-3740.php) up front (there isn't a monthly fee) for SGD 885 (682 USD) before realizing that it costs only:

1. [SGD 468 (USD 360)](http://www.samratbazaar.com.sg/component/virtuemart/netbooks-tablets/huawei-ideos-s7)
2. [SGD 549 (USD423)](http://www.itdealsg.com/products/Huawei-Ideos-S7-Tablet-Android.html)
3. [SGD 488 (USD 376)](http://www.aaas.com.sg/2010/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=255%3ahuawei-ideos-s7&catid=70%3ahuawei&Itemid=110)
4. [(SGD 324) USD 250](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/huawei-tablets/6678-huawei-ideos-s7-bestbuy-249-99-week.html)

My tablet supports GSM voice communication and I can make phone calls with it. I was basically wondering is it true that all Huawei IDEOS S7 can be used to make phone calls,

Or is it true that some Huawei IDEOS S7 have support for GSM voice communication (mine) while others do not have support for it (those *cheaper* ones shown in the list above)?

<sub>Or did I just lost $385?</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But, most notably they would tell you if there was a Voice version, and a non-voice Version.

Just like some tablets have 3G connection, and some only have Wi-Fi. They'd tell you.

However, you also have to be careful sometimes. Some sites that sell these really cheap, are like Chinese Wholesale sites, and they make counterfeit versions of these, but sell them off as the real deal.